# kafka 0.72, minimum number of brokers

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to create a [kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/07/quickstart.html) producer that sends messages to kafka brokers (and not to zoo keeper).

I know that the better practice is working with zk, but for the moment I would like to send messages directly to a broker.

To do that, I'm setting the property "broker.list" as [described in the documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/07/configuration.html). The thing is that it appears that in order for it to work it requires minimum of 3 brokers (else I get an exception).

In the [source code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/kafka/branches/0.7.2/core/src/main/scala/kafka/producer/ConfigBrokerPartitionInfo.scala) of kafka I can see:

```
if(brokerInfo.size < 3) throw new InvalidConfigException("broker.list has invalid value")
```

This is weird cause in my data center I hold only 2 kafka nodes (and 3 zk), what can I do in this case?
Is there a way go around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `brokerInfo` is obtained by splitting the **individual** broker info and **NOT** the number of brokers .. if you checked the source code more carefully you would see some thing like

`// check if each individual broker info is valid => (brokerId: brokerHost: brokerPort)`

and then they split this info as below

```
   brokerInfoList.foreach { bInfo =>
       val brokerInfo = bInfo.split(":")
       if(brokerInfo.size < 3) throw new InvalidConfigException("broker.list has invalid value")
   }
```

so every single broker expected to have an **id** with **host name** and **port** separated by the `:` delimiter 

 basically regarding the number of broker it just do this

```
    val brokerInfoList = config.brokerList.split(",")
    if(brokerInfoList.size == 0) throw new InvalidConfigException("broker.list is empty")
```

So you should be fine with that I guess, just try to pass a single broker and it should work. Let us know how it goes

Comment: You are right, this is why when I added the "0:" part to the broker identifier it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently when writing

```
props.put("broker.list", "0:" + <host:port>);
```

It works (I added the "0:" to the original string).
I have found it in section 9 of the [quick start guide](http://kafka.apache.org/07/quickstart.html).

I'm not sure I'm getting it, maybe this zero is the partition number(?) maybe something else (could be nice if someone can shed some light here).

Comment: probably this is used as the key to the map that contains the brokers info ( I am not certain though) .. what happens if you use the same `id` for multiple brokers .. e.g `props.put(“broker.list”, “0:broker1:9092,0:broker2:9092”);` .. might get some clue there I hope